# What goes wrong when I add the Where clause?

Tags: sql-server, indexing

I have a simple query:

```
 Select Distinct BOLTYPENAME, BOLTYPE.BOLTYPE From BOLTYPE
 Inner Join WORKORDER on WORKORDER.BOLTYPE=BOLTYPE.BOLTYPE
 Inner Join BOLMAIN On BOLMAIN.BOLID=WORKORDER.BOLID 
 Where BOLMAIN.CORID=156
```

When I run this query without the "Where" clause, it takes 0.1 secs. But adding the where clause causes it to take 1 minute to return. All tables have relevant indexes and they have been de-fragmented. The number of rows in the three tables is:

BOLTYPE: 11 rows

BOLMAIN: 71,455 rows

WORKORDER: 197,500 rows

Here are the execution plans:

*Without* the Where Clause (0.1 sec):

[image: Without where clause]

*With* the Where Clause (60 sec):

[image: With Where Clause]

Any idea as to what could be the issue?

Update: Here are the relevant Index definitions:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [BOLIDX] ON [dbo].[WORKORDER]
([BOLID] ASC)
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [CORIDX] ON [dbo].[BOLMAIN]
([CORID] ASC)
INCLUDE ([BOLID])
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [BOLTYPEIDX] ON [dbo].[WORKORDER]
([BOLTYPE] ASC)
GO
```

Comment: Is this also taking the same time ?

Select Distinct BOLTYPENAME, BOLTYPE.BOLTYPE From BOLTYPE, WORKORDER, BOLMAIN
 Where WORKORDER.BOLTYPE=BOLTYPE.BOLTYPE
 AND BOLMAIN.BOLID=WORKORDER.BOLID 
 AND BOLMAIN.CORID=156

Comment: Yes. It is taking the same time.

Comment: Your indexes don't look right. Can you edit with their definitions?

Comment: Paste create table scripts please

Comment: Adding table scripts would be too long as there are dozens of other tables and interlinking foreign keys. I have posted the relevant Index definitions.

Comment: Did you try rebuilding indexes, update statistics?
Are there indexes on foreign keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recreate the CORIDX index so it covers BOLID.   You're joining on BOLID, so you want it to be part of the index, not just one of the included columns.

In other words:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [CORIDX] ON [dbo].[BOLMAIN]
([CORID] ASC, [BOLID] ASC)
```

Comment: Or just create two separate indices. It doesn't look like there's a good case for a multi-column index.

Comment: He's already got two separate indices.  When there's no WHERE clause, the optimizer uses PK_BOLMAIN, which I am betting is on BOLID.   So he has PK_BOLMAIN on BOLID, and CORIDX on CORID.  I think a multi-column index will eliminate the table spool and speed up the nested loop.

Comment: Amazing!!! That solved it! I had no idea that moving a column to be  a part of an index instead of just including it in the index will make such a difference! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @navigator Including a column only means you don't need to do a table lookup for the value you're selecting (unless the index already filters the results down to a manageable amount of rows). It doesn't improve performance of *filtering by* that column. Basically, you usually want to use include for huge tables where you want to select those columns, while filtering by others - selects are *included*, and wheres are part of the index itself. Oh, and including a primary column shouldn't help at all - the index should already have the primary column. So is BOLID the PK or not?

Comment: @Luaan, thanks and very well noted. But that's also what confuses me. BOLID is the primary identity key for the BOLMain table. So why did we need to add it to another index?

Comment: @navigator Oh, I see it now. It might be a primary key, but it's not the clustered index. I usually use those two interchangeably (because the PK is usually also the clustered index), but the other indices actually refer to the clustered index, not the primary key. The execution planner probably doesn't find it favourable to go through three separate indices just for the ID column. This is one of the reasons people tend to use PK as clustered - the clustered index always includes all the columns, and is always accessible by the other indices. You've removed that by having it non-clustered.

Comment: @Luaan, I see the issue now. I think this is an error in the table. The PK should have been the clustered index but there is another unique index on a varchar column that has become the clustered index: `CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX BOLIDX ON BOLMAIN (BOLNUM ASC)`. I will need to contact the DB designers to find out why this was made clustered and get it corrected. Thank you so much!

Comment: @navigator This sounds like `BOLNUM` is the natural key for the row. It might still be a good choice, but you need to make sure your indices have better coverage, since you lost the "free" coverage through the primary key.