# Query optimization for INNER JOIN OR condition

Tags: sql-server, indexing

I have the following query that runs really slowly and I've used the estimated execution plan to narrow down the problem to the final INNER JOIN's OR condition.

```
SELECT 
    TableE.id
FROM 
    TableA WITH (NOLOCK)
    INNER JOIN TableB WITH (NOLOCK)
        ON TableA.[bid] = TableB.[id]
    LEFT JOIN TableC WITH (NOLOCK)
        ON TableB.[cid] = TableC.[id]
    LEFT JOIN TableD WITH (NOLOCK)
        ON TableA.[did] = TableD.[id]
    INNER JOIN TableE WITH (NOLOCK)
        ON TableD.[eid] = TableE.[id] 
            OR TableE.[numericCol] = TableB.[numericCol] -- commenting out this OR statement leads to large performance increase
WHERE 
    TableA.[id] = @Id
```

I have the following index on TableB:

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_TableB_numericCol_id] ON [dbo].[TableB] 
(
    [numericCol] ASC,
    [id] ASC
)
```

and on TableE:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_TableE_numericCol] ON [dbo].[TableE] 
(
    [numericCol] ASC
)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Is this query in a proc?If so you can take a look at parameter sniffing.

Comment: Do you have an index on `TableB.[numericCol]`?

Comment: You really shouldn't litter your database with NOLOCK hints unless you are cool with missing and/or duplicate data. http://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/tonyrogerson/archive/2006/11/10/1280.aspx

Comment: And the estimated execution plan is nearly useless. You should run your query and look at the actual execution plan.

Comment: Try putting the index on TableE covering both numericCol and id.

Comment: @SeanLange I ran the query and the actual execution plan was the same, that one inner join has a cost of 2.18 which goes down to practically 0 without the OR condition

Comment: @TabAlleman I tried that and it didn't change anything.

Comment: in the execution plan, what index is being used to read TableE and what index is being used to read TableB?

Comment: @TabAlleman The index I showed is the one being used for TableE and then I see a "Table Spool" on both columns TableE.numericCol and TableE.id.  Those are the only two items I see for that join, other than the join itself ("Nested Loops") which costs 90% of the execution plan.  When TableB is joined, it does not use the index I showed, it uses the index on only [id].

Answer (score 1):

See my answer here:

[What goes wrong when I add the Where clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27922772/what-goes-wrong-when-i-add-the-where-clause/27923640#27923640)

You say that you tried adding a covering index on TableE, covering both numericCol and id.   However, I suspect that the query didn't use it.  That is why you see a Table Spool.

You want to force the query to use the covering index, either by making it the only index on the table, or by including a query hint.   That should eliminate the Table Spool and speed up the Nested Loop.

Same for TableB.  If the index being used is only on Id, then it is not helping the Nested Loop which is on NumericCol.  Force the issue either by getting rid of the index on Id, or with a query hint.

Comment: I now have an index on TableE (id ASC, numericCol ASC) and an index on TableB (id ASC, numericCol ASC).  I see in the execution plan that both are being used, but it doesn't change the execution plan, there is still the Table Spool and the numbers are the same.

Comment: Hmm, can you edit your question with a screenshot of your execution plan?